# What function/method does MetaMask use to generate the entropy for mnemonic keys?

Tags: metamask, bip39, mnemonic

I am trying to understand how exactly MetaMask is generating the initial entropy to create its mnemonic key. There are questions like [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67462/generating-passphrase/67483#67483), MetaMask's documentation, or their [GitHub](https://github.com/MetaMask) but I can't find the answer I'm looking for in either one.

What is the source of entropy in MetaMask for generating mnemonic words (if they are using BIP39)? If not BIP39, what standard are they using to create mnemonic words?

Answer (score -1):

Read this article. She covers in sufficient detail the work on creating mnemonic phrases and not only.
https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-journey-from-mnemonic-phrase-to-address-6c5e86e11e14

Comment: Please post the relevant information here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly helpful and are liable to be deleted.